# How to get the last item of array without pop?

Tags: javascript

I need the same result as:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7];
var top = array.pop();
```

The problem is that `pop` removes the element from the array. To fix that I added another line:

```
array.push(top);
```

But it is annoying me, I did it four or five times in this project till now. Is there a better way?

Comment: `array[array.length-1]`

Comment: Please search before asking. It's impossible to not fall on an answer.

Comment: In addition to ```array[array.length-1]```, you can try ```const top = array.slice(-1).pop()``` or ```const top = array.slice(-1)[0]``` The original array will not be modified. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When grabbing from the end you can do `array[array.length - x]`, where `x` is the number of items from the end you wanna grab.

For instance, to grab the last item you would use `array[array.length - 1]`.

Comment: Extending the array prototype might have been the worst thing you could have done in that scenario :( But but but - I bet you've learned a lot since this q!

Comment: This worked for me. I still wanted the array to contain the last value but I wanted to check the status of that value.

Comment: so much typing. I also looked this question up because I didn't want to type array.length -1

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet same here, it would be great to have native methods like `Array.prototype.first()` and `Array.prototype.last()` corresponding to `shift()` and `pop()` respectively. Of course, typing `array[0]` is shorter than `array.first()` but the latter clearly shows the intent. And of course, `last()` will still be shorter.

Comment: Yes. I am using react and I need to type `this.props.array[this.props.array.length-1]`

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest: `array[array.length-1]`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the arr.length starting from the end such as:
arr[arr.length -1]

Bruno,

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7];
var lastItem = array[array.length - 1]
```